# I have two http requests in my application, but I want only one use 'http_proxy'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, soappy

I have an aplicattion that makes local requests http. This application also needs to make an external request http. But the server that application is located do not accept external calls. So I created a enviromnet variable 'http_proxy', but it intercept my local request http.

What I need is:
my external request use to 'http_proxy' and my local request do not use to 'http_proxy'.

For local request Im using Django Rest Framework.
For external request Im using SOAPpy. (If here I could set the 'http_proxy' environment variable it should be good!)

Here is my SOAPpy request:

```
proxy = 'https://username:password@instance.servicecom/table.do?SOAP'
server = SOAPProxy(proxy, 'http://www.service.com/')
```

Comment: Well, it looks like SOAPProxy supports `http_proxy` as a param, and even then you could probably just add additional headers as another solution. See: https://github.com/jeffkit/SOAPpy/blob/develop/SOAPpy/Client.py#L131

Comment: But that param do not instantiate the variable, right?

Comment: you said me to add additional headers, you know how should I do to django rest framework ignore the http_proxy? It may solve...

Comment: I have a proxy configured, example: proxy.teste.com:8080
when I pass http_proxy=proxy.teste.com:8080, the call will pass in proxy configured?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem! Can you elaborate?

Comment: When I set the param http_proxy to my proxy (http_proxy=proxy.teste.com:8080), it will force the call out by this proxy?

Comment: Maybe, why don't you try it and see what the request looks like?

Comment: I have tried and my return is: Connection reset by peer.

Comment: and my HTTP headers is:

*** Outgoing HTTP headers **********************************************
POST https://instance.service.com/table.do?SOAP HTTP/1.0
Host: instance.service.com
User-agent: SOAPpy 0.12.5 (http://pywebsvcs.sf.net)
Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-length: 594
SOAPAction: "getRecords"
************************************************************************

Is something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to change the lib.

I was using SOAPpy, now Im using SUDS and worked.

For some reason the param http_proxy in SOAPpy was using the proxy incorrectly.